# SQL order by highest amount of "kills divided by deaths"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table:
ID | KILLS | DEATHS
`$ratio = $kills / $deaths;`

How do I order the fields so I echo the ID with the highest ratio?

Comment: What do you want to do if people are tied for first place with the highest ratio?  Favor the highest number of kills or lowest number of deaths?  What if people with the highest ratio have identical kill and death counts?

Comment: Favor the highest number of kills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
select id from table order by kills/deaths desc limit 1;
```

Try `(kills + 0.0)/deaths` if it's not promoted to a float automatically.

Also try `kills/(deaths+0.0001)` to prevent divide by zeros..

Comment: And some consideration for when a player has `deaths=0` (shouldn't those be on the top of the list?)

Comment: Players won't have 0 deaths when they have 2000 kills :P

Comment: So, where should a player with 5 kills and 0 deaths be placed? On top or at the last places of the list? Because the `5/0` ratio is big, very big.

Answer (score 7):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT T.*,
       Ratio = kills / deaths, 
       Rank = DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY kills / deaths DESC) 
   FROM dbo.TableName T
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Rank = 1
```

Comment: I should of specified I am using MySQL.

Comment: wow that's a lot of code for something that can be done in one simple line (see BraveNewCurrency's answer). There's so much, that it makes it a very bad answer that no one should ever follow, so I've got to give you a -1 for it.

Comment: @Bohemian This answer is different, it gives the top `kills/deaths` ratio for every player. And Tim had answered before the mysql tag was added.

Comment: @Bohemian: Is this codegolf or a site for serious answers? I cannot take someone serious who measures quality in the length of code. I've omitted an explanation as OP stated that he's using MySql. However, this answer might be useful for someone looking for a t-sql approach and who wants all columns of the top-ratio rows. Imho it's very readable and efficient.

Comment: Oh it is all those things you say; it's just that your answer doesn't belong under this question. Find a question that asks for what it does and put it there. I'm not saying that you are a bad person. A downvote is supposed to convey "not useful" - and that's what your answer is *for this question*. It's not going to teach junior coders anything worthy. IT is overkill, and that's a bad thing. "Over achieving" in code is an anti-pattern. Doing the simplest thing that works is a very good policy.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, won't PARTITIONing by ID (which is presumably unique) mean that each player is ranked #1 in his partition containing ... just him?  Separately and of less importance, using DENSE_RANK will not break a tie, though the OP hasn't yet told us how he wants to handle ties.

Comment: @pilcrow: I've asssumed that ID is a foreign-key column. Ratio of kills/death sounded as if OP wanted a highscore function, then `DENSE_RANK` is more appropriate then `ROW_NUMBER` which just returns one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, you may want to clarify in the answer that you're assuming ID is an FK to a *non-unique* column -- I (and most others) assumed it represented a unique player.  I agree that DENSE_RANK is probably appropriate, but many folks don't think about collisions and don't articulate their requirements.  You can certainly read the OP as asking for a single record...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, cast(Kills/Deaths as float) FROM KillsDeaths
ORDER BY (Kills/Deaths) DESC
```

Comment: TOP is not the mysql way. It's LIMIT, and it's at the end.